# Ignore user and password from database_url in prisma

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'm trying to connect my next.js app to my locally hosted mongodb instance. I can't use Docker or the online free tier for this. I'm getting the below error in my terminal:

`The provided database string is invalid. MongoDB connection string error: Missing delimiting slash between hosts and options in database URL.`

from using this URL connection string `DATABASE_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/projectcontrol`

I beleive it is complaining that I haven't provided a user or password as it expects however I can't get a user and password set up through MongoDB Compass. I've tried using the terminal to add a user to the database however I get Authorisation Failuer when trying to connect using Compass.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: see when this error will be triggered: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-rust-driver/blob/a2e277e68dcdf3cb59b77e7381ac0e33ffd1c2bb/src/client/options.rs#L1626

Comment: Try adding a delimiting slash to the end of the database URL.